# Issue in taxonomy term with hyphen(-) in url drupal7

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy called free-choices.But the contents are not listed when hyphen(-) in the taxonomy name.The pages with taxonomy name without hyphen is listing contents.How to solve this issue?I checked this validation criteria .But this is not working.How to solve this issue?
 [image]
[image][image]How to solve this issue in the same views?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a taxonomy term to be recognized wholly, then you definitely do not want to divide it with spaces, so uncheck the `Transform dashes in URL to spaces in term name filter values`.

Also check on the `Use path alias instead of internal path` option and set the correct path component. It shows set to 1, but most probably it's different component in the taxonomy path alias.

Additionally, try to use term ID instead of term name.

Comment: If it is unchecked also it is not working.

Comment: Try `Use path alias instead of internal path` and set the correct path component.

Comment: Yes i checked the use path alias here.But not working

Comment: Change the path components, it is definitely not 1 in your case. Also I'd recommend you to register and start accepting asnwers as otherwise less people will want to help you with your questions.

Comment: Thanks.But all other categories are working except with hyphen.

Comment: Try to use term ID instead of term name in the `Filter value type` option, so then you won't deal with the hyphen issue at all.

Comment: Hyphen issue is solved by  passing Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth) to the views.But data from 3 taxonomies are missing.